# Recover old ufasoft coin wallet from a wallet.db file

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery

I found a wallet.db on my computer which was used with the Ufasoft Coin application. Of course I want to see if there is anything left in this wallet so I downloaded the Ufasoft software from some shady download page but I can't find any way to open the old .db file, anyone tips?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if you don't trust a piece of software, don't give that software access to a wallet file.  That's just asking to be ripped off.

I am unfamiliar with "Ufasoft", but a quick web search makes it appear to be a small software company that at one point in time created a CPU/GPU bitcoin miner and wallet.  If that's the case, then you may need to reach out to that company for support.  The wallet file may not conform to the Bitcoin standard.  In fact, it looks like the wallet supported many coins, so it might be some hybrid multi-coin wallet format.

Best of luck.  When you use non-standard wallets, you'll end up not being able to ask the larger community for support.